# Faço uma alteração no CSS porém apos reload volta ao normal

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte `View`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero, mudar a posição do `CheckBox`, então na `View` temos uma `div`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Entrei no CSS, achei a class `CheckBox`:

```
.radio input[type="radio"],
.radio-inline input[type="radio"],
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: 4px \9;
```

Então alterei o valor das propriedades `margin-left:` para 1px e a propriedade `margin-top:` para 1px, ficando:

```
.radio input[type="radio"],
.radio-inline input[type="radio"],
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"],
.checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px \9;
}
```

E então automaticamente a pagina ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao clicar em atualizar, o `CheckBox` volta para a posição original, e o CSS continua com os novos valores, ou seja 1px para `margin-left` e 1px para `margin-top`

Atualização:

Alterei o CSS direto no codigo-fonte, em modo Debug funcionou apos fazer um Master-Refresh (CTRL + F5), porem, ao realizar a publicação, é mostrado no modo antigo ainda.

Então limpei o FTP do servidor, e fiz uma nova publicação, do zero.
Limpei o cache do navegador e utilizei o Chrome em modo `Anonimo`

E mesmo assim, ainda continua aparecendo do jeito antigo.

Comment: Você alterou as configurações de CSS no navegador ou editou o arquivo no código fonte? Se tiver alterado o código fonte, já testou um *hard refresh* no navegador? (CTRL + F5 na maioria dos navegadores).

Comment: Alterei direto no código fonte, testei o (CTRL + F5) em modo Debug e funcionou, porem quando faço a publicação ele mostra ainda do modo antigo.. tentei excluir o arquivo BootStrap do servidor e enviar a nova versão, e não deu certo...

Comment: Parece ser problema de cache mesmo, tenta adicionar um "identificador de versão" onde você insere tua folha de estilos no html, algo assim: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?v1">`. Colocando o `?v1` (pode ser o que preferir depois do `?`) o navegador irá buscar novamente teu `css` igonorando o cache. O ideal é termos um código compilado e minificado, mas se não for possível essa é uma boa maneira de evitar problemas com cache. Se for esse o problema.. hehe

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel duas sugestões: **1-)** inclua na pergunta isso sobre onde você mudou o CSS e o fato de já ter alterado no servidor **2-)** tente a sugestão do Pedro no comentário dele acima.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior cara, nao acredito que seja cache, ate pq, limpei o cache do navegador, e tambem utilizei ele em versão `Anonima`

Comment: @Renan atualização feita.

Comment: Você informou que em sua máquina após dar um (CTRL+F5) funcionou porém no servidor mesmo limpando cache e tudo mais continua do modo antigo, certo? Já tive alguns problemas semelhantes com hospedagens locaweb. Alguns serviços utilizam cache de servidor que se renova a cada x tempo (horas, minutos, depende da configuração) e a forma que encontrei para resolver isso foi a dica de @PedroCamaraJunior. Coloque um `?v=1` ao final da chamada do css e nos diga o que aconteceu.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior poderia me dar algum direcionamento? como posso pesquisar sobre isso? identificador de versão css? Obrigado.

Comment: Então, @ThomasErichPimentel relendo novamente sua pergunta, e se você diz que não é cache, será que seu css não está sendo sobescrito? Faça um teste, crie uma nova classe para seu checkbox e coloque na sua própria folha de estilos e nos conte o resultado. :)

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior realmente estava sendo sob-escrito, criei uma nova classe, e então deu certo. obrigado..